# How to get the SAM compatible domain name on a Hybrid domain computer?

Tags: windows, winapi, credential-providers, windows-credential-provider

EDIT:
Thank you @RbMm for your clarification questions!

I am implementing MFA in a credential provider (not a wrapper provider). One of the options I must support is to verify the same UPN is used for logging in to the computer and validating with the MFA provider. I use LsaLogonUser, ImpersonateLoggedOnUser and GetUserNameEx(UserNamePrincipal) to obtain this information. This works in most environments; however, on a computer connected to a hybrid Azure AD domain, LsaLogonUser fails. This lead to an investigation the results of which are elaborated below:

I have a computer belonging to an AzureAD hybrid domain, but I have no way of getting the SAM-compatible domain name from the AzureAD domain name.
For example,
I can log in with a user whose AzureAD upn is, for example's sake user@domain.com. The SAM-compatible name is localdomain\localuser.
GetUserNameEx(NameUserPrincipal) reutrns user@domain.com
GetUserNameEx(NameSamCompatible) returns localdomain\localuser
HOWEVER in the following code, TranslateName fails with GetLastError() returning ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN.

```
TCHAR validBuffer[MAX_PATH+1];
ULONG nValidSize = MAX_PATH;
TranslateName("user@domain.com", NameUserPrincipal, NameSamCompatible, validBuffer, &nValidSize);
```

I have also tried the following APIs without success, they all fail with different return values:

- [GetComputerObjectName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/nf-secext-getcomputerobjectnamea) fails with any value passed to NameFormat
- [GetCompterNameEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getcomputernameexa) fails with ERROR_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO for any relevant value of NameType
- [NetWkstaGetInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmwksta/nf-lmwksta-netwkstagetinfo) does not return any useful information in any field
- Also, if you look at the computer's join information in This PC > Properties > Advanced System Properties, u see it as part of a workgroup, not a domain.
  -if you run the [dsregcmd /status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/troubleshoot-device-dsregcmd) command:

  - executed within the aforementioned user's logon session: the 'Diagnostic' part lists the localdomain in the output
  - executed from a command prompt running with the LocalSystem account, the output does not list the localdomain anywhere.

**An important point** (thanks @RbMm) - the code services a Windows Credential Provider, when using the 'Other User' tile. I am trying to pre-verify the entered credentials using LsaLogonUser, before serializing them successfully in my implementation of ICredentialProviderCredential2::GetSerialization. Using 'user@domain.com' fails, while using 'localdomain\user@domain.com' or 'localdomain\localuser' succeeds. When logging in with Windows' built in password provider, using 'user@domain.com' of course works. Maybe I should be using a different authentication package for LsaLogonUser?

I am STUMPED.

thanks for anyone's help..

- Uriel

Comment: *I can log in with a user* - so you have user token. query *TokenUser* for get user *Sid* and call *LsaLookupSids* for this. you get exactly what you want.

Comment: Have to try `DsEnumerateDomainTrusts` call.

Comment: @RbMm 
Thanks for the suggestion; I forgot to mention that this is done in the context of a Windows credential provider, when logging in from the 'Other User' tile. The problem is, I cannot login using the user's credentials - using LsaLogonUser with user@domain.com fails with 'no such domain' error and only using localdomain\localuser ot localdomain\user@domain.com works. I will edit my question to include this information.

Comment: @UrielG - unclear context - from where, for what, in what situation you call `LsaLogonUser`. are you wrap built-in credential provider or not. what really credential enter user, etc..

Comment: @RbMm I have edited the question to include additional information. THANK you for the clarification questions :)

Comment: *I am trying to pre-verify the entered credentials* - in this case you need wrap some built-in credential provider and use already formatted `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION` for call `LsaLogonUser`. exist different providers and different input is used. say password, pin(*NgcPinProvider*), wlid.

Comment: @RbMm, yes that's what I thought, that's why I asked if maybe I should be using a different authentication package for LsaLogonUser in my question... BUT- which authentication package should I use and what is the format of the serialization? From this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-primary-refresh-token) I surmise the provider is CloudAP. But what is the format of the input data? It's undocumented... :(

Comment: you need use `NEGOSSP_NAME_A`  Negotiate authentication package Id. and usually [`CredPackAuthenticationBufferW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-credpackauthenticationbufferw) used. for instance WLID provider use `CRED_PACK_ID_PROVIDER_CREDENTIALS` flag in call. and then [`SspiEncryptAuthIdentityEx`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-sspiencryptauthidentityex). in lsass - the *LiveSsp* process buffer. in your case this may be *CloudAP*. unfortunately i dont know how join to azure for test. if can do this - can research how

Comment: so  when you use Negotiate authentication package Id - *negoexts.LsaApLogonUserEx2* is invoked, which in case `SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_EX[2]` call wst packages - LiveSsp, pku2u,  CloudAP. until value other than `SEC_E_NO_AUTHENTICATING_AUTHORITY` returned

Comment: *which authentication package should I use* - 100% Negotiate authentication package (*NEGOSSP_NAME_A*), *what is the format of the serialization?* - think *CredPackAuthenticationBufferW* with *CRED_PACK_ID_PROVIDER_CREDENTIALS* in case online identity

Comment: this plugins is registered under `LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IdentityStore\Providers`

Comment: *MicrosoftAccountCloudAP* (*livessp*) use user mail in place User and *MicrosoftAccount* in place Domain. how accept *CloudAP* need look. i however use only wrapper solution - here not important format of data. i can pass it as is to *LsaLogonUser* - because i receive it ready from wrapper